# How to put a table in the end of the content

Tags: php, html, css

okay, so my head is going to explode right now, i'm searching 5 hours non stop for my problem..
i want the menu2.html which is inside a table, to appear on the end of the page, After the end of the Content!
i tried a lot, like:
1-position: absolute; bottom: 0;
2-position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 150px; etc etc...
But this is not what im looking for!
I could put the menu2 after the content only by editing the top:150 But there are a lot of pages with different contents, so the menu2 doesn't suit in the other pages!
I hope you can help me.
This Is My PHP file:

```
  <style type="text/css">
  .menu2 {
  background-image: url('<?=$profpic;?>');
  background-attachment:fixed;

  background: yellow;
  }
  </style>
  <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table width="100%" height="58%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="heading">
     <tr> 
       <td>
       <?php include('menu.html');?>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><img src="pictures/logo.png" width="1335" height="300"></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="85%" height="1%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
   <tr> 
       <td>

       <?php include('menu2.php');?>

         </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
  <?php
  $profpic = "pictures/bg.jpg";
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You should start with valid html, multiple `html`, `body`, etc. elements are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do here, but I'll take a shot at helping you. First of all, you can't have multiple `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags on the same page. Only one set of these are allowed. Secondly, change the file type of menu2 to php instead of html if you want to include it there.

```
<style type="text/css">
.menu2 {
background-image: url('<?=$profpic;?>');
background-attachment:fixed;
position: absolute;  
background: yellow;
}
</style>
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" height="58%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="heading">
   <tr> 
     <td>
     <?php include('menu.html');?>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><img src="pictures/logo.png" width="1335" height="300"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table width="85%" height="1%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
 <tr> 
     <td>

     <?php include('menu2.php');?>

       </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
<?php
$profpic = "pictures/bg.jpg";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**menu2.php**

```
<div class="menu2">
//menu2 contents
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help me!
well, all i wanna do is to put that menu which is included in the table, as a footer! i hope that now it's more clear to you, sorry if i confused you! :S

Comment: Ok, well if you remove the additional tags as I have, and change the file to php, you can put all your footer code in menu2.php and include it.

Comment: i just deleted all my code, and i put the one that you posted here, and also changed the html file to php, but it just keep showing in the same position..
the menu2.php file contains a menu that i've created with CSS menu creator, and there are adverts in it, which i wanna show on the bottom of the page, after the content of any page..

Comment: Remove position: absolute;

Comment: just like the black menu table on the bottom of this pic:
http://zurb.com/blog/system/images/815/original/footer-2012.jpg?1365807030

Comment: i did it..but it shows in the same place again :S
if you wanna take a better look into it please, ive opened team viewer right now:
my id: 807 259 728
pass: 9964
if you can, join please :/

Comment: Where is the menu positioned on the page?

Comment: i uploaded a pic so you you can have a clearly image
http://i.imgur.com/2lKRGaL.jpg

Comment: Try removing height="1%" from your bottom table

Comment: Which file are the social media icons coming from?

Comment: i did, but nothing changed, i dont understand why it doesnt wants to work -_- i just also uploaded the menu2.php (if needed)
http://www.filedropper.com/menu2

Comment: they're coming from the menu2.php, this is what i want to put as a footer, the socal media icons, at the end of any page..

Comment: It seems to me that the menu2.php (which you can change back to menu.html if you want, just leave out the extra tags), is outside the `<html>` `</html>` tags or there are extra duplicate tags somewhere. You will need to put the code from all files in the question.